# Unknown option to `s' error sed while appending one text file content to other

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sed

At the end of the 8th line, I want to append content of another text file using sed.

When running the command

```
sed -i "8s/$/$(sed 's:/:\\/:g' recentchanges.txt)/" message2.json
```

I get the error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 56: unknown option to `s'
```

Whereas `sed 's:/:\\/:g' recentchanges.txt` works and I get the content of the text file as expected.

What's wrong in my sed command? Let me know if there are any alternate ways to update the same file like awk etc.

## Content of message2.json

```
{
   "Subject": {
       "Data": "Test email sent using the AWS CLI",
       "Charset": "UTF-8"
   },
   "Body": {
       "Text": {
           "Data": "This is the message body in text format.",
           "Charset": "UTF-8"
       },
       "Html": {
           "Data": "This message body contains HTML formatting. It can, for example, contain links like this one: <a class=\"ulink\" href=\"http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide\" target=\"_blank\">Amazon SES Developer Guide</a>.",
           "Charset": "UTF-8"
       }
   }
}
```

======================================

## Content of recentchanges.txt

```
Mon, 13 Apr 2020 11:49:26 +0530   User1 // Job1
Mon, 13 Apr 2020 11:18:26 +0530   User2 // Job2
Mon, 13 Apr 2020 13:03:59 +0530   User3 // Job3
```

================================================

### Expected output

```
{
   "Subject": {
       "Data": "Test email sent using the AWS CLI",
       "Charset": "UTF-8"
   },
   "Body": {
       "Text": {
        "Data": 
        " Mon, 13 Apr 2020 11:49:26 +0530   User1 = Job1 \n  Mon, 13 Apr 2020 11:18:26 +0530 User2 = Job2 \n Mon, 13 Apr 2020 13:03:59 +053   User3 = Job3 ",
        "Charset": "UTF-8"
       },
       "Html": {
           "Data": "This message body contains HTML formatting. It can, for example, contain links like this one: <a class=\"ulink\" href=\"http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide\" target=\"_blank\">Amazon SES Developer Guide</a>.",
           "Charset": "UTF-8"
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `awk` tag?

Comment: The error means that the effective command contains a `/` somewhere. Have you considered the `r` command instead? If you show input and expected output, help can be more specific.

Comment: Seeing that you're manipulating JSON, you'd almost certainly be better off using `jq` instead of sed.

Comment: Benjamin, I think using jq I can't update one json with the content of another text file.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can. If you show your inputs and expected output...

Comment: I have updated the description.

Comment: `jq` can *absolutely* be used for this purpose, and is the right tool for the job.

Comment: Your message2.json file isn't valid json... There's an extra comma in there, and an unquoted string *blob* and more...

Comment: I have rectified that error.

Comment: BTW, note that your "expected output" isn't valid JSON either; to be valid JSON, f/e, the newlines need to be replaced with `\n`s. This is part of the reason to use `jq`; it knows how to do all those things for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the `//`'s to `=`'s in `jq` itself:

```
jq --arg changes "$(< recentchanges.txt)" '.Body.Text.Data = ($changes | gsub("//"; "="))' message2.json
```

(Or `--rawfile changes recentchanges.txt` instead of `--arg ...` with a new enough `jq`.)

Answer (score 2):

`sed` is the wrong tool for this job; use `jq` instead:

```
jq --rawfile changes <(sed -e 's:/:\\/:g' <recentchanges.txt) \
  '.Body.Text.Data = $changes' \
  <in.json >out.json
```

Comment: The OP needs to filter the recent changes before insertion. A process substitution would work (@SubitDas `--rawfile changes <(sed 's://:=:g' recentchanges.txt)`) or, if the `--rawfile` option (jq 1.6) is not available, a command substitution can be used as well (`--arg changes "$(sed ...)"`).

Comment: @luciole75w, indeed; adopted your suggestion of a process substitution.

Comment: @luciole75w It can also be done purely in `jq`; see my answer for an example.

Comment: @Shawn Ah sure, you are right ! And it's more efficient than my suggestion.